# Detecting failures in nosetests

Tags: testing, tags, nose

I have something like this as a sampler:

```
class TestMe(object):
    def test_a(self):
        assert 'c' == '1'
        print "I am here"
```

and nosetests gives me the following error correctly

```
 nosetests test_me.py --tc-file ../configs/test_config.yaml -v

test_me.TestMe.test_a ... FAIL
```

======================================================================

```
FAIL: test_me.TestMe.test_a
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/tests/test_me.py", line 7, in test_a
    assert 'c' == '1'
AssertionError
```

---

On the other hand, if I have a script like this which is also run by nosetests:

```
class TestMe(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...............
    def test_b(self):
        status = {'status': 'pass'} #by default
        if status:
            print("PASS: Connection was successful")
        else:
            print("FAIL: Connection was NOT successful")
            status['status'] = "fail"  #updating status in dictionary
        return status
```

When I run the above with nose tests, the it says:

```
nosetests test_110.py --tc-file ../configs/test_config.cfg -v
test_110.TestMe.test_b ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.026s

OK
```

Whereas only when I look at the log file I know that it has failed. How can I make the failure show up on the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert on status['status']=='passed' or you can `raise AssertionError('connection failed')` in your failing if case statement.